# SpeechToText using web sockets from iOS

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Does anyone have sample code for this, or know if it's possible ?  I love the service, but recording it first then sending it for processing takes a minimum of 5 seconds, which is too long for real world use.

Using the service found here https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/websockets.shtml

Comment: I believe this is how Siri works (record audio, send when completed). I doubt that if Apple didn't implement Siri in a asynchronus way, it must be difficult/not worth it to do so

Comment: You should look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-nodejs

Comment: take a look at the ios-sdk which supports speech to text. There is a work in progress to support interim results https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

The last release of the Watson Developer Cloud [ios-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.2) supports continuous listening and will stream the audio from your microphone to the service using websockets.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/tree/master/Examples/SpeechToText) example.